# Как выбрать верхний элемент с использованием сss

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Проблема заключается в следующем. Есть верстка такого типа:

```html
    <ul class="products columns-3">
      <li class="post-23">
        <a href="" class="">
          <img class="img" alt="">
          <h2 class="product__title"></h2>
          <a href="#" class="add" style="cursor: pointer;"></a>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Могу ли я селектором css при наведении на ссылку с классом `add` выбрать тег `img` и изменить ему `background-color`.
Или для этого необходимо использовать связку с JS.
Спасибо за советы!

Comment: только скриптом.... есть у CSS псевдокласс focus-within но там очень специфичная особенность и я бы не рекомендовал использовать в текущем случае

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только скриптом. Есть у *CSS* псевдокласс **[:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)**, но там очень специфичная особенность и я бы не рекомендовал использовать в текущем случае.

```js
$('.products').on('mouseenter', '.add', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('img').addClass('test');       
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
}
.test {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products columns-3">
  <li class="post-23">
    <a href="" class="">
      <img class="img" alt="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NKk6rGDpq6Y/sddefault.jpg">
      <h2 class="product__title"></h2>
      <a href="#" class="add" style="cursor: pointer;">ссылка</a>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сам использовал mouseover(), но подумал, что возможно есть решения проще с помощью css. В любом случае ваше решение работает на отлично!

Answer (score 2):

Есть небольшой лайфхак, благодаря которому можно решить Вашу задачу, не используя js: нужно в вёрстке поменять местами .add и .img, а с помощью относительного позиционирования - поменять обратно (тогда визуально картинка будет идти до ссылки, но в потоке - после, и можно с помощью css менять её внешний вид).

Вёрстку Вам, кстати, в любом случае придётся править, потому что у Вас ссылка в ссылке - это ошибка и работать такая конструкция не будет.

```css
.add, .img {
  position: relative;
}
.add {
  top: 85px;
}
.img {
  bottom: 85px;
}
.add:hover ~ .img {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="products columns-3">
  <li class="post-23">
      <a href="#" class="add" style="cursor: pointer;">ссылка</a>
      <h2 class="product__title">Заголовок</h2>
      <img class="img" src="" alt="Картинка">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Вот. Ждал такого ответа.

Comment: С другой стороны, там такая вложенность, что можно было завязаться и на <a> который выше и на <li>.

Comment: @UModeL, там вообще не очень понятно, чего хотел добиться автор, вкладывая ссылку в ссылку )) Но вопрос был именно про ссылку с классом .add, поэтому я и предложил такое решение

Comment: Думаю, что в вашем ответе можно даже использовать flex column для <li> и поменять order на обратный. Тогда можно отказаться от position и размеров.

Comment: @UModeL, это даже лучше моего ответа :) Думаю, Вам стоит предложить этот вариант от себя

Comment: это будет просто вариант вашего ответа. Суть та же - сначала поменять разметку.

Comment: Дело в том, что я привел часть разметки, которую формирует модуль на сайте (не знаю почему автор решил именно так ее реализовать) и, чтобы внедрить все нужды клиента, решил не лезть в модуль, а использовать css и js (правка там не особо большая). Спасибо вам за советы, бесспорно вы правы, что вкладывать ссылку в ссылку это извращение).